# Ineqality of heights of points on an elliptic curve

Tags: inequality, elliptic-curves

I am currently reading rational points on elliptic curves by Silverman. In exercise $3.2$ $(b)$ of Chapter $3$, it asks (regarding an elliptic curve of the form $C: y^2 = x^3+ax^2+bx+c$)

> Prove that there is a constant $\kappa$ which depends only on $a,b,c$ so that for all rational points $P_1$ and $P_2$,
>   $$h(P_1+P_2)+h(P_1-P_2) \leq 2h(P_1) + 2h(P_2) + \kappa$$

Where $h(P) = \log(H(P))$ and $H(P) = H(x(P)) = H(\frac{a}{b}) = \max\{|a|, |b|\}$ is the height of a rational number. I realize this amounts to proving
$$H(P_1+P_2)H(P_1-P_2) \leq H(P_1)^2 H(P_2)^2 *\kappa^{\prime}$$
I attempted a proof modeled after Silverman's outlined proof of a Lemma used to prove Mordell's Theorem, but I reached a weird conclusion. This is my attempt: We have
$$x(P_1 \pm P_2) = \bigg(\frac{\pm y_2 - y_1}{x_2-x_1}\bigg)^2-(a+x_1+x_2)$$
$$=\frac{y_2^2 \mp2y_1y_2+y_1^2-(a+x_1+x_2)(x_2^2-2x_1x_2+x_1^2)}{x_2^2-2x_1x_2+x_1^2}$$
$$=\frac{\mp2y_1y_2+(y_2^2-x_2^3-ax_2^2)+(y_1^2-x_1^3-ax_1^2)+x_1^2x_2+x_1x_2^2+2ax_1x_2}{x_2^2-2x_1x_2+x_1^2}$$
using $y_i^2 = x_i^3+ax_i^2+bx_i+c$
$$=\frac{\mp2y_1y_2+b(x_1+x_2)+2c+x_1^2x_2+x_1x_2^2+2ax_1x_2}{x_2^2-2x_1x_2+x_1^2}$$
replacing each coefficient with an arbitrary rational number, we have
$$=\frac{Ay_1y_2+Bx_1^2x_2+Cx_1x_2^2+Dx_1x_2 + E(x_1+x_2)+F}{Gx_2^2+Hx_1x_2+Ix_1^2}$$
we can assume $A-I$ are integers, as multiplying across by a common denominator gives integers. Also, it was shown earlier in the text that each rational point satisfies $x = \frac{m}{e^2}$ and $y = \frac{n}{e^3}$, and they satisfy the inequalities
$$e \leq H(P)^{1/2}, \text{    } n \leq KH(P)^{3/2}, \text{    } m \leq H(P)$$
for some constant $K$. Substituting these in and clearing denominators on the numerator and denominator by $e_1^4 e_2^4$ give (after simplifying)
$$\frac{An_1e_1n_2e_2 + Bm_1^2m_2e_2^2+Cm_1e_1^2m_2^2+Dm_1e_1^2m_2e_2^2+Em_1e_1^2e_2^4+Ee_1^4m_2e_2^2+Fe_1^4e_2^4}{Gm_1^2e_2^4+Hm_1e_1^2m_2e_2^2+Ie_1^4m_2^2}$$
Thus 
$$H(P_1 \pm P_2) \leq \max\{|An_1e_1n_2e_2 + Bm_1^2m_2e_2^2+Cm_1e_1^2m_2^2+Dm_1e_1^2m_2e_2^2+Em_1e_1^2e_2^4+Ee_1^4m_2e_2^2+Fe_1^4e_2^4|, |Gm_1^2e_2^4+Hm_1e_1^2m_2e_2^2+Ie_1^4m_2^2|\}$$
(either the numerator and denominator are in simplest form or they reduce, in which case the inequality still holds). The first element of the max function is
$$|An_1e_1n_2e_2 + Bm_1^2m_2e_2^2+Cm_1e_1^2m_2^2+Dm_1e_1^2m_2e_2^2+Em_1e_1^2e_2^4+Ee_1^4m_2e_2^2+Fe_1^4e_2^4|$$
$$\leq |An_1e_1n_2e_2| + |Bm_1^2m_2e_2^2|+|Cm_1e_1^2m_2^2|+|Dm_1e_1^2m_2e_2^2|+|Em_1e_1^2e_2^4|+|Ee_1^4m_2e_2^2|+|Fe_1^4e_2^4|$$
$$\leq H(P_1)^2 H(P_2)^2 \Big(|AK_1K_2| + |B| + |C| + |D| + 2|E| + |F| \Big)$$
The first step is by the triangle inequality, and the second by the aforementioned inequalities on $H(P_i)$ and $m_i, n_i, e_i$. Similarly, the second element of the max function is
$$|Gm_1^2e_2^4+Hm_1e_1^2m_2e_2^2+Ie_1^4m_2^2|$$
$$\leq |Gm_1^2e_2^4|+|Hm_1e_1^2m_2e_2^2|+|Ie_1^4m_2^2|$$
$$\leq H(P_1)^2 H(P_2)^2 \Big(|G| + |H| + |I|\Big)$$
Therefore, if we let $\kappa^{\prime \prime} = \max\{|AK_1K_2| + |B| + |C| + |D| + 2|E| + |F|,|G| + |H| + |I|\}$
$$H(P_1 \pm P_2) \leq H(P_1)^2 H(P_2)^2 \kappa^{\prime \prime}$$
If this inequality holds, then we have
$$H(P_1 + P_2)H(P_1 - P_2) \leq \Big(H(P_1)^2 H(P_2)^2 \kappa^{\prime \prime}\Big)^2$$
But this was not the desired inequality. My question is: if my proof was correct, where did I go wrong? Is there another set of inequalities that should have been followed or does it still somehow follow from what I have shown already? Thank you,

Comment: I don't know if this is critical, but I don't follow your reasoning starting where you say $A-I$ are integers (you mean variable $A$ to $I$, right??). That's fine, but I don't see how it is necessarily compatible with also assuming that that fraction is in least terms.

Comment: @TokenToucan I do mean variable $A$ to $I$. Also, I wrote $H(P_1 \pm P_2) \leq $ the max of the numerator and denominator. If the fraction is in least terms, it is an equality. If not, the height of the sum of the points is less than the max of the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Sure, I guess, but if they reduce then your bound improves, and right now your bound is too big. Hard to say if that's the real error, though.

Comment: There's no way to improve the bound by reducing the fraction. For example, $b$ can be any rational number. It is necessary in the proof to have integer coefficients, so for each undetermined coefficient that is some combination of the rational numbers in $a,b,c$, one multiplies by a common denominator to acheive all integers. Therefore, the coefficients $A$ through $I$ are arbitrary, on which one can impose no divisibility restrictions, and none of the $n_i,m_i, $ or $e_i$ factor.

Comment: Ok, I see now (by referring to Silverman) is that when you say "arbitrary" you do not in fact mean arbitrary. If they really were arbitrary then they absolutely do matter to the bound, eg if you let them depend on $x_1$ etc, things will go rather badly. Instead they are just fixed but uninteresting constants.

Comment: Sorry if I'm mistaken, but how about this way? $x_1\pm x_2=\frac{m_1}{e_1^2}\pm\frac{m_2}{e_2^2}=\frac{m_1e_2^2\pm m_2e_1^2}{e_1^2e_2^2}$. We get
$|m_1e_2^2\pm m_2e_1^2\le |m_1e_2^2|+|m_2e_1^2|\le 2H(P_1)H(P_2)$ and $|e_1^2e_2^2|\le H(P_1)H(P_2)$. So, we have $H(P_1\pm P_2)\le 2H(P_1)H(P_2)$ and so $H(P_1+P_2)H(P_1-P_2) \leq 4H(P_1)^2H(P_2)^2$.

Comment: @mathlove the addition formula on elliptic curves is not the same as for rationals. The formula for the $x$ coordinate is $x_3 = \lambda^2 - (a+x_1+x_2)$ where $x_1,x_2$ are the $x$ coordinates of the first two points and $\lambda$ is the slope between the first two points.